# Monitor never goes to sleep

Tags: display, power-management, unity-2d

Am running Natty with Unity 2D

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 3):

click the top left ubuntu icon, search for "power" and click on "Power Management" and check the settings at the bottom: "Put display to sleep when inactive for: " see this setting is checked to "never". If it is, then that's why your monitor won't sleep :) if not, then this is probably beyond me I'm afraid :(

Comment: Did this solve the problem? :)